# How to .htaccess redirect file name to be url parameters on new site?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I want to be able to redirect url such as `domain.com/cat-1/long-tail-kw.html` to new domain and url such as `differentdomain.com/goodname.php?id=long-tail-kw`

Also, the `cat-1` will change often, it could also be `cat-271` or whatever number.

How can I do this in .htaccess file?

Also, the redirect must work with this code that sends the people who come from bing ONLY to the new url.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} (bing)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://differentdomain.com/goodname.php?id=long-tail-kw
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert a new rule for this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} (bing)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?sub\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://differentdomain.com/goodname.php?id=long-tail-kw [L,QSA,R=302]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?sub\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^cat-\d+/(.+?)\.html$ http://differentdomain.com/specificname.php?id=$1 [L,QSA,R=302]
```

Comment: I tried that but didn't work. I forgot to mention that the it will be subdomain as the original url. Something like sub.domain.com/cat-[N]/some-random-url.html and I want it to go to newdomain.com/specificname.php?id=some-random-url

Comment: Thanks, it works now.. though I needed to delete the last line and move RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} (bing) after the Rewriteengine on

Comment: ok try now in a new browser. Basically keep bing rule before this rule.

Answer (score 0):

In the `RewriteCond` you can use the `regular expression`. So I think you can try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} domain.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^cat-([0-9]+)long-tail-kw\.html$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://differentdomain.com/goodname.php?id=long-tail-kw
```

Comment: I think I expressed myself not too accurately. The original url could be anything but the format is something like /cat-[N]/some-random-page-title.html and I want that "some-random-page-title" to be sent forward as a parameter in new site url.